# ImportError: cannot import name '_gi' from partially initialized module 'gi' (most likely due to a circular import)

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu

Looks like I have broken my python installation when I wanted to switch to python 3.8. Using Ubuntu 18.04. Trying to use the `gi`, gives the following error:

```
$ python
Python 3.8.1 (default, Dec 31 2019, 18:42:42) 
[GCC 7.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
 >>> from gi.repository import GLib, Gio
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    from . import _gi
ImportError: cannot import name '_gi' from partially initialized module 'gi' (most likely due to a circular import) (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/__init__.py)
```

Tried running update-alternatives for python, but it tells me there is only one python alternative configured (3.8).

Tried to reinstall python3-gi and python3.8. Still the same problem

Comment: Reverting the `/usr/bin/python` and `python3` symlinks back to `python3.6` will most likely fix this for you. The real question here would be: how to make python 3.8 the default on Ubuntu without breaking a bunch of stuff?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I had the same issue. I linked python3 to python3.6, for me it was pointing to 3.8. That solved the issue.

```
cd /usr/bin/
rm python3
ln -s python3.6 python3
```

Thats all. Now my system started working fine.

Comment: This solution resolved my problem. Why does it work?

Comment: `unlink python3` can also be used instead of `rm python3` since it is anyhow used in the next step.

Comment: I'd prefer to have 3.8 as my default

Comment: I recommend using `update-alternatives` instead but this is a good solution

Comment: If python3.6 is installed and working fine in system, this should work.

Comment: ln -s python3.6 python3  -- this work!

however i tried to use ln -s python3.8 python3  <--- this doesn't work

Answer (score 30):

Install `gi` for python 3.8: `python3.8 -m pip install pgi`
Then, instead of `import gi` use:

```
import pgi
pgi.install_as_gi()
from gi.repository import GLib, Gio
```

Alternatively, you can force install PyGObject for python 3.8:

`sudo python3.8 -m pip install --ignore-installed PyGObject`

which should allow one to `from gi import ...` as before.

Comment: This solved my issue (Python 3.8.5, Ubuntu 18.04, linking didn't work).

Comment: Got this error:
Command "/usr/bin/python3.8 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-5puaelnl/pycairo/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-jkdw0o7c-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-5puaelnl/pycairo/

Comment: Installing PyGObject for python3.8 worked for my system using python3.8 as a default. I guess the problem happened when I installed python3.8.10 and lost dependencies for gnome-terminal requirements.

Installing PyGobject for python3.8 also requires pycairo as a dependencies and that might lead you to another problem with missing cario library. When it happens, install  libcairo2 like "sudo apt install libcairo2-dev" (assuming you are on ubuntu)

Comment: This should be the accepted solution as it will not require changing anything.

Comment: I ran into the same problem after setting Python 3.9 as the default on a system where 3.8 was the distro default (Mint 20). `sudo python -m pip install --ignore-installed PyGObject` initially failed and I had to install a few extra packages first: `sudo apt install python3.9-dev libcairo2-dev libgirepository1.0-dev` - then it worked.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem on ubuntu 18 as python3 was referring to python3.9.
In order to solve it, I changed the alternative for python3:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config python3                                                                                                                                                                  
There are 2 choices for the alternative python3 (providing /usr/bin/python3).

  Selection    Path                Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/bin/python3.9   2         auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/python3.6   1         manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/python3.9   2         manual mode
```

By choosing number 1, now python3 points to python3.6 and everything works fine again

Comment: Exactly the same.  I got that error when using Python3.9 and the solution is to use this to switch back to Python3.6.

Answer (score 9):

For me the workaround was to create a symlink:

```
cd /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/
sudo ln -s _gi.so _gi.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```

and it solved the problem for me.

Comment: For me, having the `_gi.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so` file, I did the opposite (`sudo ln -s _gi.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so _gi.so`) and it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The reason of this error is that this app can't find the matched Python version of `_gi_cairo.cpython-(version)-x86_64-linux-gnu.so.`
Normally, this unmatched situation is caused by some wrong mixed usage of different versions of Python.

So basically, you can try to switch your Python version ( to the default version of your OS). Or you can go to '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi' and create a new .so library file:

```sh
cp _gi_cairo.cpython-(old version)-x86_64-linux-gnu.so _gi_cairo.cpython-(new version)-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```

or

```sh
ln -s _gi_cairo.cpython-(old version)-x86_64-linux-gnu.so _gi.so
```

Answer (score 2):

Found answer here https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1709787:

> The cause is - /usr/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/gi/_gi.cpython-38m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so has incorrect name:
>
> sh-5.0# python3 -c 'from gi.repository import GLib'
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "", line 1, in 
> File "/usr/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/gi/**init**.py", line 42, in 
> from . import _gi
> ImportError: cannot import name '_gi' from 'gi' (/usr/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/gi/**init**.py)
>  sh-5.0# mv /usr/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/gi/_gi.cpython-38m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so /usr/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/gi/_gi.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
>  sh-5.0# python3 -c 'from gi.repository import GLib'
>
> Note that since 3.8.0a4, the "m" is not supposed to be there. Is it somehow hardcoded?
>
> sh-5.0# python3-config --extension-suffix
> .cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so

in my case it was

```
$ sudo ln -s /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/_gi.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/_gi.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
$ sudo ln -s /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/_gi_cairo.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/_gi_cairo.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```

Comment: didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You could instead also try to create a Python Venv, soley for your application. This avoids messing with system dist-packages, by deleting, removing, force-installing them in some way shape or form. I'd not recommend any of that.

1. Create Venv `python3 -m venv /path/to/newVenv`
2. Activate Venv `. /path/to/newVenv/bin/activate`
3. (You should have an Indicator somewhere in bash now.)
4. Install PyGObject
5. Install other necessary dependencies (If those requirements are not in public pypi repos, you may find them inside the deb packages - use `apt download package` and open with archive manager to check the /usr/lib/python3 folder inside the deb, just copy them to to the same folder **inside** the venv.)
6. Run your application (while still inside the Venv) with `python3 /path/to/script`  - (some applications just are python scripts. libremenu, apt, ...; so you can just run them with python explicitly - example: `python3 /usr/bin/libremenu`. If the dependencies are all available inside the venv, even if there is an broken system package, it will use the one from inside the venv - which is great.)

Install necessary dependencies, including PyGObject (which includes gi)

Answer (score -4):

Have same issue, can't load module from script folder. In my case work if i changing workdir for example (but only for inline command):

```
cd /tmp; python -c 'from gocd import Server'
echo $?
0
```

After copy script to /tmp, it's does't work

```
cp gocd.py /tmp
cd /tmp; python -c 'from gocd import Server'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/gocd.py", line 3, in <module>
    from gocd import Server
ImportError: cannot import name 'Server' from partially initialized module 'gocd' (most likely due to a circular import) (/tmp/gocd.py)
```

Comment: How is this an answer to the question?