# Difference between module pgi vs gi in GStreamer? TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

Tags: python, linux, gstreamer

I'm confused in using pgi in this python code.

I had some troubles but solved via under link. (using pgi instead of gi)
[ImportError: cannot import name '_gi' from partially initialized module 'gi' (most likely due to a circular import)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59838238/importerror-cannot-import-name-gi-from-partially-initialized-module-gi-mo)

But when I ran main code, I have another trouble.

main code

```
#import gi
import pgi as gi
gi.install_as_gi()
gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0')

    def start_tracker(self, args):
        """Deepstream function for detection and tracking"""
        # Check input arguments
        if len(args) < 2:
            live_camera = True
            stream_path = "/dev/video0"
        elif len(args) >= 2:
            live_camera = False
            stream_path = args[1]

        number_sources = 1
        # Standard GStreamer initialization
        GObject.threads_init()
        Gst.init(None)

# Results
Gst.init(None)
File "<string>", line 5, in init
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

So I tested whether gi versus pgi differs.

gi (python 3.6)

```
python3.6
Python 3.6.9 (default, Mar 10 2023, 16:46:00) 
[GCC 8.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import gi
>>> from gi.repository import Gst
>>> Gst.init(None)
[]
```

pgi (python 3.8)

```
python
Python 3.8.0 (default, Dec  9 2021, 17:53:27) 
[GCC 8.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pgi as gi
>>> gi.install_as_gi()
>>> from gi.repository import Gst
>>> Gst.init(None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 5, in init
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

How can I return Gst.init(None) via pgi?